# Connect remote MySQL Client to MySQL Server

Tags: mysql8

I can connect locally but not remotely.

On my client I have:

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

On my server I have:

```
mysql  Ver 8.2.0 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

I try to connect like:

```
mysql -h 10.0.1.242 -P 33060 -u bob -p
```

I get (the screen hangs for quite some time after I enter password):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-webserver-instance:~$ mysql -h 10.0.1.242 -P 33060 -u bob -p

Enter password: 

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.1.242:33060' (110)
```

My user has:

```
CREATE DATABASE pets;
CREATE USER 'bob'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON pets.* TO 'bob'@'%'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I've edited `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` trying:

```
[mysqld]
bind_address            = 0.0.0.0
```

```
Jan 17 01:02:20 ubuntu-database-instance mysqld[4672]: 2024-01-17T01:02:20.265066Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/>
```

```
[mysqld]
bind_address            = 0.0.0.0
mysqlx_bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

```
Jan 17 01:16:37 ubuntu-database-instance mysqld[4783]: 2024-01-17T01:16:37.880551Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '0.0.0.0' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/my>
```

I'm kinda stumped.

Answer (score 0):

got it!

```
iptables -I INPUT 6 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect locally: On the same Mysql SQL Server, use:
mysql -h localhost -P 33060 -u bob -p

If you can connect, then check the firewall on both sides: Server and client

Comment: Almost right - on mysql "localhost" means use a Unix domain (filesystem) socket rather than a network socket. A more useful diagnostic would have been `-h 127.0.0.1` AND `-h 10.0.1.242`